# Calling smart contract with hardhat can return either value or dictionary

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I have a simple function in a smart contract

```
function getBalance() external view returns (uint) {
    requireMembership(msg.sender);
    return coins[msg.sender];
}
```

When I call it from hardhat `Contract` object it returns a number. On the other hand, when I call this

```
function vote(bytes32 merkleHash, bytes32 randomHash) external votePeriod returns (uint) {
    votes.push(Vote (msg.sender, merkleHash, randomHash));
    return votes.length - 1;
}
```

it returns more data

```json
{
  hash: '0x80edd9baca248c121bdd026343c842f9b608ac1827c63998dde48d2c3a87b2c6',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: '0xcc1a5d8ac8d92f98e4f1247c4d76e83e27b167cdc29d2fe962f10ee773eaa509',
  blockNumber: 4,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  confirmations: 1,
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "1590942713" },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1000000000" },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "2181885426" },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "29025624" },
  to: '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3',
  value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  nonce: 2,
  data: '0xeeaaf19ded2380097cd5db2b14288f4081b387c78bb556bba20557ee9580b19c4c77aa01e57feaac04642d236597ea01c4f788ded7c59047121e4d1a42fa2daaaa22350a',
  r: '0xdddc05db4d271a1a4c7e1d31bf56fc7e052a5e0d0f15a9309e8ce492a3e46da1',
  s: '0x2968ea8648e0102437efa9c710ecc2188d72e0bb9afab5343b2062a4d5a5ee5b',
  v: 0,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 31337,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Is this because `getBalance` is just a `view`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is this because `getBalance` is just a `view`?*

Yes, with combination that you're using Hardhat (and what I'm assuming from the context, Ethers.js).

Ethers.js and some other libraries use the contract ABI (specifically the `stateMutability` property of each function) to decide on default behavior when invoking a function. Whether to invoke it using a read-only [call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) or a read-write [transaction](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sendtransaction).

EVM by design exposes returned values for calls, but does not expose them for transactions.

Since your script operates outside of EVM, it does not have access to return values from a function invoked by a transaction. And Ethers.js authors have decided in such case to return the transaction data instead of nothing.